# How do you grapple in Dead Rising 3?

Tags: dead-rising-3

I just started playing Dead Rising 3 on the Xbox One. I got to [the first grapple](http://youtu.be/6-FYCv1uqhU?t=5m58s), and I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do. The top of the screen says "Perform a gesture to escape a grapple" - what does "gesture" mean in this context? Is it something to do with Kinect?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a circle at the bottom off the screen with a red line around it. You have until the line runs out to either perform the gesture or to press the button onscreen.

Answer (score 1):

You can also switch gesture based grapple escapes off in the Kinect settings of Dead Rising 3 (along with all the rest of the Kinect features) so that you have to do QTE type button presses instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to do a Kinect gesture - just flail around and it will fling off the zombie!

Comment: I don't think the devs would put a feature that is a disadvantage to most players. Unless, the game REQUIRES Kinect, in which case, disregard this comment.